# Volume Problems After Render (DaVinci Resolve)

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve, volume

In Resolve, my audio is mixed exactly how I want it. However, when I render the video out and play it back on other devices, certain pieces of audio are bizarrely off in terms of volume.

Example image:

[image]

Both faders in this image are the Main, final decibel level for the entire project. In example A, you can see it peaking about -2 to -5dBFS. In example B, it is somewhere around -12dBFS. HOWEVER, after rendering the video and listening back, the -12dBFS is audibly much louder than the -5dBFS. How can this be? I thought the decibel levels were pretty cut and dry. How can something be so off?

Thanks for your help.

P.S. Both pieces of audio come from the same source, only altered for volume.

Comment: A complete guess from someone who’s unqualified in the audio department, but I think having your monitoring volume at anything less than 100% might cause this.  I’d have to test to be sure, but because the control to change it is relatively hidden, it’d be my first guess.  I think you alt/option click the mute icon to expose the volume slider if I remember correctly off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem was actual a sneaky setting hidden deep in my audio settings called "Loudness Equalisation." It was unnecessarily making quieter audio much louder, and vice versa.

Comment: I'd run your mix through a LUFS meter - your original looks a bit hot for the regular streaming services, the auto-levelled version actually looks better.

Comment: @nevermind_me_ You should either "answer" (not "comment") your question (now that you "know the answer", or delete it (if you think it won't help others).